# Variable not being defined

Tags: javascript, variables

So I'm trying to get the variables `x` and `y` in the following code to determine the position of the image with the class `myElement`. On click it should set the top and left style to whatever the variables are (position of the cursor). When I test it out it just defaults to `undefined`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body onclick="getCoord(event)" style="height:2000px;">
<h2>click</h2>
<p id="display"></p>
<script>
function getCoord(event) {
 var x = event.clientX;
 var y = event.clientY;
 var coord = "x:" + x + "y:" + y;
 document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = coord;
 console.log(x);
 console.log(y);
 document.getElementById('myElement').style.position = "absolute";
 document.getElementById('myElement').style.top = y; //or whatever 
 document.getElementById('myElement').style.left = x; // or whatever]
};
</script>
<img id="myElement" src="https://picturethismaths.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/fig6bigforblog.png?w=419&h=364">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put `+'px'` after your `x` and `y` when you set `left` and `top`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## CSS Measurement

You had forgotten to add [the measurement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length) the numbers are to be interpreted as.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onclick="getCoord(event)" style="height:2000px;">
<h2>click</h2>
<p id="display"></p>
<script>
function getCoord(event) {
 var x = event.clientX;
 var y = event.clientY;
 var coord = "x:" + x + " y:" + y;
 document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = coord;
 console.log(x);
 console.log(y);
  var myEle = document.getElementById('myElement'); // no need to use 3 times
 myEle.style.position = "absolute";
 myEle.style.top = y + "px"; // plus "px"
 myEle.style.left = x + "px"; // plus "px"
};
</script>
<img id="myElement" src="https://picturethismaths.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/fig6bigforblog.png?w=419&h=364">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Such an obvious thing that I missed!

Comment: It happens to us all @KenzoEngineer :-)